COUNTIFS WITHIN DATE RANGE GOOGLE SHEET
I need to get the count of my NOTICE SENT weekly. I have updated as of date to identify the week I need in the report.
FORMULA:
=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$8,$F$2,$C$3:$C$8,$F3,$D$3:$D$8,">="&$B$1,$D$3:$D$8,"<="&$B$1-6)

Link Sheet Here:

Google Sheets and Excel is 2 different platforms please update the tag or accept any edits that are more accurate in your case.  Can you clarify your expected result here? You want to get only the same week? or is it based on the days like +-7 days?

Your formula almost correct. You just put date value wrongly. See my answer please.

Do not use ALL CAPS in title or body. It is considered rude.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Use QUERY() function like-
=QUERY(B3:D,"select C, count(B) where B='" & F2 & "' and D>= date '" &TEXT(B1-6,"yyyy-mm-dd")& "' and D<= date '" & TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")& "' group by C label count(B) ''")

Or COUNITIFS()-
=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$8,$F$2,$C$3:$C$8,$F3,$D$3:$D$8,">="&$B$1-6,$D$3:$D$8,"<="&$B$1)



Hi Harun24hr is it possible to use my formula in countifs?

@RhenzIdolIiSanPedro Yes, I already shown your formula in my answer. Check it.

it works. thanks

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Using COUNT and FILTER
You can also try this other way.
=COUNT(FILTER(B3:D8,C3:C8 = a, B3:B8 = F2, ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKNUM(D3:D8) = WEEKNUM(B1))))

You can use filters then just count. Data reference cells are based on your sheet.
Adding this formula for a dynamic spilling formula:
=BYROW(F3:F4, LAMBDA(a, COUNT(FILTER(B3:D8,C3:C8 = a, B3:B8 = F2, ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKNUM(D3:D8) = WEEKNUM(B1))))))

